# How to define a class with dynamic attributes?

Tags: python, class-attributes

In my project, I need to create a class with attributes passed by a `dict`, something like this:

```
class_attributes = {"sensor": Nested(Sensor),
                    "serial_interface": Nested(SerialInterface)}
class MSchema(marshmallow.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = cls

    attr = class_attributes
```

I need that "sensor" and "serial_interface" to be in the class, and can be access using `MSchema.sensor` or `MSchema.serial_interface`.

Comment: What exactly is "Nested"?

Comment: ``marshmallow`` does some heavy meta-programming, including a meta class (i.e. running at class creation). Are you sure you *only* need ``MSchema.sensor`` and ``MSchema.serial_interface`` to be accessible, or do you need them at class creation?

Comment: @Ivan Nested is a Field class for Flask Framework.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, marshmallow have meta class, so i need theses attributes in class creation

Comment: What's `cls`? It's undefined in your post; can we assume it's simply a placeholder for this example?

Comment: I wonder if any thought has even been given to augmenting the definition of the `class` statement to allow something like `class MSchema(...): **class_attributes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the metaclass of `ModelSchema` directly, rather than defining the class declaratively using a `class` statement.

```
m = marshmallow.ModelSchema

class_attributes = {
    "sensor": Nested(Sensor),
    "serial_interface": Nested(SerialInterface)
}

m = marshmallow.ModelSchema
mc = type(m)
MSchema = mc('MSchema', (m,), {
    'Meta': type('Meta', (), {'model': cls}),
    **class_attributes
    })
```

---

In case you aren't aware, a `class` statement is just a declarative syntax for calling `type` (or some other metaclass) with 3 arguments: the name of the class, a tuple of parent classes, and a `dict` of class attributes. The `class` statement evaluates its body to produce the dict, then calls `type` (or another given metaclass), and binds the return value to the name. Some simpler examples:

```
 # Foo = type('Foo', (), {})
 class Foo:
     pass

 # Foo = Bar('Foo', (), {})
 class Foo(metaclass=Bar):
     pass

 # Foo = Bar('Foo', (Parent,), {'x': 3})
 class Foo(Parent, metaclass=Bar):
     x = 3

 # def foo_init(self, x):
 #     self.x = x 
 # Foo = Bar('Foo', (), {'__init__': foo_init})
 class Foo(metaclass=Bar):
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.x = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand the question to 100%, but have you tried using [setattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)?

Example code would look like the following:

```
m_schema = MSchema()
for key, value in class_attributes.items():
    setattr(m_schema, key, value)
```

`setattr(object, string, value)` takes an object to set attributes on, a string for the attribute name, and an arbitrary value as the attribute value.

Comment: This doesn't give the metaclass a chance to process the attributes, if necessary.